# Emacs 28: How to use `RET` without exiting a recursive edit within a keyboard macro?

Tags: keyboard-macros, recursive-edit, emacs28

Now that I switched to using GNU Emacs 28.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0, NS appkit-1671.60 Version 10.14.6 (Build 18G95)) of 2022-05-11 I can no longer end my use of my keyboard macro that allows me to rename a file, by using the "Return/Enter" key (`RET`).

In that macro I enter a recursive edit (using `C-u C-x q`) to allow me to edit the file name and change it.  I now have to use `M-C c` to terminate the recursive edit.

If I try to finish the recursive edit with `RET` I get an error `Not in most nested command loop`, and I have to use `C-]` to abort the recursive edit and regain use of the mini-buffer.  I find that if I do use `C-]` in this manner, another `RET` will exit use of the mini-buffer and the file name is changed as desired.

Can this be fixed, or can I somehow work around it, to get back to being able to end the keyboard macro after using `RET` to enter a file name?

My keyboard macro is defined as follows:

```lisp
(fset 'rn "wR\C-y\C-u\C-xq")
```

This is meant for use in a Dired buffer.

Comment: I could be wrong, but this sounds like a bug (maybe a design bug). If you don't get a good answer to the question here, consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```lisp
  (defalias 'rn
    (kmacro "M-x r e n a m e - f i l e <return> C-x r i a <return> C-x r i a C-f"))
```

I assume that

- the `register` `a` contains the base file name, and
- the file being renamed----which is in `register` `a`----is the visited file.

The `End of buffer` error thrown by the `C-f` seems to help you edit the string.  A subsequent `RET` does the rename.

***Note that the macro definition doesn't enter recursive levels.  Without the `C-f`, the macro just zips through to executing the command.   My contention is that it should stay put in the minibuffer, waiting for "minibuffer exit" to arrive.***

[**Question**: *If the keystrokes that form the macro are typed manually, then after the second `C-x r i a`, you are still in mini-buffer because you haven't exited the mini-buffer yet.  So, shouldn't the above `kmacro`, **without the trailing `C-f`**, also leave your cursor in the mini-buffer, and not exit it?*

I am using `kbd-macro-query` for the first time.   So, I don't have a reference on what the behaviour used to be.  My gut feeling says that the `kmacro` shouldn't zip through to doing `rename-file` when you haven't exited the `minibuffer`.]

I am on `emacs-29.0.50 (dtd. 2022-07-07)`,  and [`kmacro` uses `oclosure-lambda`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/0fc9808dedc24e843bfbbfe3d3a3930167873fa7/etc/NEWS#L1248), and so behaviour on `Emacs 28.1` and my own `Emacs 29.0.50` may not be directly compared.  But, I do see the same exact behaviour as you do.

---

Btw, the error is coming from [`exit-minibuffer`: minibuffer.el#L2452](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/bda6e9a226f42d74176cba640dda7dfef25b764b/lisp/minibuffer.el#L2452), and the commit in question is [Make recursive minibuffers and recursive edits work together](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/commit/203e61ff837128b397eb313a5bb1b703f0eae0ec) .

This [(emacs-devel) Re: Stop frames stealing eachothers' minibuffers!](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2021-02/msg00683.html) message seems like a good starting point for further exploration.

[**One more Question**:  *Are you using `helm` etc., and have fancy customizations.  Since the commit in question "somehow" concerns `minibuffer-follows-selected-frame`, it would be good to check (or eliminate) any fancy behavour.  FWIW, I have tested my suggestion using `emacs -Q`*]

Answer (score 0):

This qualifies as comment ... Since there is too less a space to give elaborate comment, I am turning it to an answer.

I have `emacs-gtk 27.1+1-3.1+b1` on `Debian`, and running it with `-Q` flag

- the second version is equivalent of what the original poster says.  I confirm that after that the macro is paused with `C-u C-x q`, a simple edit and `RET` successfully does the rename.
- the first version, "the non-recursive version with `C-f`" exactly same as `emacs-29.0.50` dtd `.2022-07-07`  Without the `C-f`, `rename-file` just zips through, and I am not offered an opportunity to edit.  My contention is that it shouldn't zip through, because one hasn't done "minibuffer exit".

```lisp
;; Note the `C-f` which makes the minibuffer stay put
(fset 'rn27-non-recursive
      (kmacro-lambda-form [?\M-x ?r ?e ?n ?a ?m ?e ?- ?f ?i ?l ?e return ?\C-x ?r ?i ?a return ?\C-x ?r ?i ?a ?\C-f] 0 "%d"))

(fset 'rn27-recursive
   (kmacro-lambda-form [?\M-x ?r ?e ?n ?a ?m ?e ?- ?f ?i ?l ?e return ?\C-x ?r ?i ?a return ?\C-x ?r ?i ?a ?\C-u ?\C-x ?q] 0 "%d"))
```